# How do i handle phone number, address and email in nextjs

Tags: next.js, mailto

Currently I am using nextjs/Link for handling tlf number and email inside of a contacts section in my footer. I use href property to send the user to mailto or directly to google maps when they click on the respective link. I read that using next/link for this purpose is not a good practise. What should i be using instead?
here is a snippet of my code:

```
interface Props {
  contact: ContactType;
}

function Contact({ contact }: Props) {
  return (
    <Link href={contact.href ?? ''}>
      <a className="flex gap-x-5" target={contact.target ?? ''}>
        {contact.icon ? (
          <div className="relative w-5 h-5">
            <Image width={15} height={15} src={contact.icon} />
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <p> {contact.name} </p>
      </a>
    </Link>
  );

}

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 7):

If your links lead to an external resource then you can use regular `<a>` tag without Next.js `<Link>`, same with mail or phone links and etc. Basically `Link` is only needed if you want to have SPA internal navigation between your own routes (navigation that will not reload the page).